# Is there any function in iOS to pause UIImageView animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Is there any function in iOS to pause UIImageView animation like startAnimating() and stopAnimating() functions are there to start and stop an animation respectively?

```
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: "Chicken"))
let playButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
let stopButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    let imagesArray = [UIImage(named: "Chicken"), UIImage(named: "Burger"), UIImage(named: "Fruits"), UIImage(named: "Pizza"), UIImage(named: "Sandwich")]

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 200, height: 200)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.animationImages = imagesArray as? [UIImage]
    imageView.animationDuration = 2
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 4

    playButton.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 320, width: 40, height: 40)
    playButton.setTitle("play", for: .normal)
    playButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    playButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(playButton)

    stopButton.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: 320, width: 40, height: 40)
    stopButton.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
    stopButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    stopButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    stopButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(stopButton)
}

func playButtonAction(sender: UIButton){
    imageView.startAnimating()
}

func stopButtonAction(sender: UIButton){
    imageView.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate, explain what's the issue are you facing.

Comment: Show your code, you have tried...

Comment: Please, this question is extremely vague - based on your comments on the answers. You really should update your question with **details** that would help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
You can not pause animation read this document
[UIImageView - Animation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview)

UIImageView has not any function/property member that handle pauseAnimation operation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use this by resume and pause layer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let images = [UIImage]()
     let  imageView =  UIImageView()
    imageView.animationImages = images //images is your array
    imageView.startAnimating()

    self.pauseLayer(layer: imageView.layer)

}

func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}

func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

Comment: OP is asking to pause animation not remove the animation.

Comment: it's not achieving pause action @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: @shashank   Check this solution again we can use layer

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya Check it we can use layer to do it

Comment: Pausing the layer works great. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just for example

```
NSArray *myAnimationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"myImageFirst.png"],
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"myImageSecond.png"], 
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"myImageThird.png"], 

  nil];
//Create imageview object
UIImageView *animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
animatedImageView.animationImages = myAnimationFrames;
[animatedImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

Swift version

```
  let arrayImages = [UIImage(named: "myImageFirst.png"), UIImage(named: "myImageSecond.png"),UIImage(named: "myImageThird.png")]

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.animationImages = arrayImages as? [UIImage]
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()

    //for stopping 
    imageView.stopAnimating()
```

Comment: Have you seen the Swift tag on the question?

Comment: Added Swift code. I assume developer has knowledge of Swift as well as Objective-C

Comment: Why would you make such assumption when only one of those tags is added?

Comment: I don't see any pause action achieved with this code @Gagan_iOS